# Need Helping in Writing Text Files in VB

Tags: database, vb.net, file, text

I am trying to write code to write text files in VB. So far, I have this and Visual Studio is coming up with some errors. I have 2 errors on my code and I have an "Else" must be proceeding by a matching "if" and a "end if" must be proceeding matching "if" error.

```
 Private Sub btnload_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnload.Click

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "test.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        txtload.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd.objReader.Close()
        objReader.Close()


        Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: your If is written as the single line version: `If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then...`  they dont have an `Else`

Comment: Just insert a carriage return after `Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

- your file needs a system path
- if you just want to write to a text file, add text to it -you don't need to read it in

Try writing directly to the file:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt",
```

"This is new text to be added.",True)